# Sync Framework using RetryApplyingRow results in infinitive loop

Tags: c#, synchronization, conflict, microsoft-sync-framework, syncfx

I am using Sync Framework 2.1. I am implementing conflict handling but I don't understand why it is not working:

Here is my conflict handling code:

```
public void OnErrorOccured(DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Conflict.Type == DbConflictType.LocalUpdateRemoteUpdate)
    {
        int remoteValue = (int)e.Conflict.RemoteChange.Rows[0][e.Conflict.RemoteChange.Columns["MyValue"]];
        int localValue = (int)e.Conflict.LocalChange.Rows[0][e.Conflict.LocalChange.Columns["MyValue"]];

        if (remoteValue > localValue)
        {
            // Overwrite only MyValue column
            e.Conflict.LocalChange.Rows[0][e.Conflict.LocalChange.Columns["MyValue"]] = remoteValue;

            e.Action = ApplyAction.RetryApplyingRow; // Retry with new changes
            // Same conflict will be raised again and again and again
        }
        else
        {
            // Overwrite entire local record
            e.Action = ApplyAction.RetryWithForceWrite;
            // The else is working properly
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried to make e.Conflict.RemoteChange equal to e.Conflict.LocalChange to merge all values to both DataTables:

```
// Overwrite only MyValue column
e.Conflict.LocalChange.Rows[0][e.Conflict.LocalChange.Columns["MyValue"]] = remoteValue;

// Copy rest of all columns
e.Conflict.RemoteChange.Rows[0][1] = e.Conflict.LocalChange.Rows[0][1];
e.Conflict.RemoteChange.Rows[0][2] = e.Conflict.LocalChange.Rows[0][2];
e.Conflict.RemoteChange.Rows[0][3] = e.Conflict.LocalChange.Rows[0][3];
```

Bot also that does not help.

**- What is wrong in my code?**
**- I haven't found any good examle using RetryApplyingRow. Can you provide?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try updating the RemoteChange and set the conflict resolution to RetryWithForceWrite

Comment: @JuneT unfortunately thats also not working. Even if I change all columns to `null` in RemoteChange, RetryWithForceWrite will take the normal values from the remote side. It looks like I need to change it somewhere else.

Comment: You're updating the RemoteChange from the conflict object right? Yes, that will not work. By remote change I meant the actual change dataset. That should have read Remote Change instead of RemoteChange which is the same as in your code.  I.e., e.Context.Dataset.Tables[yourtablename]. grab the pk of the row from the conflict object, locate it on the context dataset and update it from there.

Comment: Yeah that works. Thanks!! But it doesn't feel right to be hounest. First This way only solve the conflict locally (Resolution is not detected as a change so server and client are not equal anymore). Second its a RetryWithForceWrite (overwrite local) instaed of Retry again after solve (It looks like RetryApplyingRow is meant to apply your merged resolution). I still don't have an answer how RetryApplyRow supose to work. Do you know?

Comment: it's not a hack actually, the context.Dataset is where you would normally intercept changes to do some extra processing. RetryApplyingRow will keep on raising a conflict in your scenario because the conflict has not been addressed. modifying the incoming row value doesnt change the conflict type.

Comment: I take my word back about RetryWithForceWrite. Thats not correct and I understand now why its actually not a hack :) So problem solved for `RetryWithForceWrite` :). About `RetryApplyingRow`: How do I address the conflict. Changing context.DataSet doesn't work in combination with `RetryApplyingRow`. Do I need to change the Local record in database itself so that SelectRow Stored Procedure now reads new data (not sure that's gonna work. not tested) or are there possibilities to address the conflict in memory (OnErrorOccured event) without hitting the database?

Comment: RetryApplyingRow is normally used for errors, like for example, a locking issue, you can retry applying it after a while when a lock has been released. or maybe data issues, let's say the target table has a not nullable column and the row to be applied has a null value...

Comment: Ah ok. That make sence. Thanks June, your comments were very helpfull helping me out!